# Refresh Dojo Datagrid

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I am trying to refresh a Datagrid when stores data changes.

```
//Store for my datagrid
var myStore= new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url : '/my/store.html', clearOnClose:true, urlPreventCache:true } );
```

**When I make an ajax call to save/update data for the grid, in callback function of ajax call I call:**

```
function myCallBack() 
{
myStore.close();
Alert("Data Saved Successfully");
}
```

The function that updates the records in Grid, calls **myStore.save()** right before exiting.

**This scenario works fine in FireFox but grid is not refreshing in IE8**

Any pointers or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. You first need to close the store on your grid:

```
myGrid.myStore.close();
```

Then set the store back to the grid with new data:

```
myGrid.setStore(newStoreData);
```

For more information, follow [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#refreshing-the-content-of-a-grid)

Answer (score 2):

You can also reset the query in order to execute it again. Follow the tutorial in order to set up the page: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_grid/

in the example datagrid with an in memory store:

```
  require( ["dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/domReady!"],

          function ( DataGrid, ObjectStore, Memory ) {
             var formsList = [
                {id:1, name:"Jim", department:"accounting"},
                {id:2, name:"Rosenblumentalovitsch", department:"engineering"},
                {id:3, name:"Mike", department:"sales"},
                {id:4, name:"John", department:"sales"}
             ];
             formStore = new Memory( {data:formsList, idProperty:"id"} );

             formGrid = new DataGrid( {
                store:dataStore = ObjectStore( {objectStore:formStore} ),
                query: {id: "*"} ,
                structure:[
                   { name:"Form", field:"name", width:"100%" }
                ]
             }, "grid" );
             formGrid.startup();
          } );
```

when adding an element to the `formStore` the data grid is not automatically refreshed. Here is the addForm function with the refresh:

```
function addForm( evt ) {
   // set the properties for the new item:
   var myNewItem = {id:5, name:"Jim 2", department:"accounting"};
   // Insert the new item into the store:
   formStore.add( myNewItem );
   formGrid.setQuery({id: "*"}); //this row executes the query again, thus refreshing the data grid
}
```

Comment: You may also do formGrid.sort() - it also calls _refresh on the grid.